# Saving photos from Google Contacts API to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, google-contacts-api

I'm creating an app that allows users to import and save their contacts from their connected Google accounts, including the contacts' photos. I've been able to successfully integrate the authorizations and retrieve the contacts.

Where I'm stuck on and can't figure out is the photos. I've been able to successfully get the photos following this (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo), but I can't seem to save the photos to a storage like S3. I can even save the file locally, but I have no idea how to save the file to a remote storage.

I'm working on Ruby on Rails, and using Carrierwave for file upload. I used carrierwave-data-uri addon, but nothing is saved to S3.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward if you use the `aws-sdk` gem (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby).  Refer to amazon's documentation on  how to do this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html